# How to call php page from another php function

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, isset

I have 3 PHP pages.

1.**View.php** : which calls another PHP page by using the onclick event (js)

```
 echo "<td><a id='execute' href='' onclick='execute_upgrade_page($workflow_id,".$row['Task_Number'].","demo.php")' title='Click to Execute the workflow'>
       <i class='fa fa-forward' style='font-size:16px'></i> </a></td>";
```

Javascript

```
function execute_upgrade_page(id,tnum,scriptName){
        $.ajax({
            url: scriptName,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id,
                tnum:tnum,
                scriptName:scriptName
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

2. in the **demo.php** script, I am doing isset of the values like the below - it's working.

   ```
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['tnum']) && isset($_POST['scriptName']))
    { }
   ```
3. Now I am not getting how to call this same script from any other PHP file?
   In another PHP page ie **modify.php:**

   ```
    $get_script_name = "select * from  details where `Workflow_Number` = $workflow_id and Task_Number = $task_num";                   
    $check_prep_task_details=mysqli_query($con,$get_script_name);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_prep_task_details) > 0)
    {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_prep_task_details)) {
                    $db_script = $row['Script_Name'];
                 if($db_script == "demo.php")
               // here i need to redirect  with 3 parameter. 
            }
    }
   ```

Comment: You can't `here ... redirect  with 3 parameter`, that would just redirect the AJAX request which wouldnt send the client elsewhere. You could return something to JS and have it direct the user, something like `window.location.href=`.. Your SQL also is open to injections, parameterize and use prepared statements.

Comment: @user3783243  without on click function how to call ajax inside PHP while? I am new  to this and not able to get you fully

Comment: You don't call AJAX from PHP. PHP is server-side, AJAX is client-side. You call AJAX from Javascript running a browser. An AJAX request sends a HTTP request to the server, which trigger a PHP script. The PHP script can then provide a response back to the browser.

Comment: You can't call AJAX in PHP. PHP runs first, that's why you need the AJAX. In place of `// here i need to redirect  with 3 parameter. ` do something like `exit('Code:1');` then in place of `console.log(data);` do `if(data == 'Code:1') { window.location.href= URL with three parameters;}`. This is rough example. Look up real syntax, also might need to trim the PHP return in JS.

Comment: If you want to directly invoke one PHP script from another PHP script, normally you do so via the use of `include` or `require` - check the PHP manual for those functions if you need examples. But I'm not sure it makes sense in this case, because your demo.php appears to expect POST parameters to be delivered to it from the browser. Another PHP script can't do that (unless it has itself had POST values already sent to it in the current request). What are you actually trying to achieve here? I sense an XY problem, so maybe describe your overall purpose here before we get into specific code.